# Custom Related list actions

Tags: administration

I have a object lets say Parent__c then I created a field with the lookup relationship on the same object which is named Parent__c.myField__c. My question is when i click the New button on the related list, It shows a form that will create a new record. Is there any way to make the form select an existing entry?

EDIT:

So i have a new field called Child_Product__c and its self related to the Product2 object. My question is: is there any way if the setup of a field is self related to its object to show a picklist of existing values similar to the last picture without having to code.
[image: Fields]

So when i go to a product detail related lists, it shows.
But when i click new, it shows a new form
[image: Related List]

Such as this:
[image: New Form]

But how I want it to behave is instead of a new form, select an old product data entry.
[image: Desired Behavior]

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough, please update your question with some screenshots. From what I understand, if the related list already has an existing entry/record, you will not have to click on New, but click on Edit on the related lists records.

What do you mean by entry? are you referring to the Parent__c.myField__c field? do you want this fields value to be taken to the new form that you opened?
In that case, you will have to create a custom visual force page on related lists object and add a custom button next to the New button. This custom page can be made so it takes values from its parent object.

Comment: Hey Niveth. First of all thanks. I have updated my query hopefully its a bit more clearer now.

Comment: Hey, so 2 instances, we click new button on your related list 'child records', it should open a form, where you should be able to select a dropdown of existing values with the other details shown in image 3? or instead of the new button, you should have a dropdown of all the "entries" or some sort of value that links to another record and just add it to the related list.